# JavaScript getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a HTML page, with several links on it. I want to make all those links open in a different tab, so I tried using

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    foo[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

But why is that not working (as far as I know, `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array, I might as well be wrong)?

Comment: please define "not working" :)

Comment: What do you think? I explained my task, i.e. "I want to make all those links open in a different tab", and I showed my code. I would have thought it would be obvious that by "not working" I meant that that task was not being accomplished, i.e. the links' target attibute was not changed. :)

Comment: Strange problem. This one works on both Chrome and Firefox (tried with JSFiddle).

Comment: Aah, thanks to Engineer, I now know this is another onload problem!

Comment: it does not matter what I think. for me it was not sufficient to know that it does not work. I wanted to know the symptoms because I was hoping that if I know the symptoms I can help you, but now I have given up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `setAttribute` and put your script inside of `window.onload` handler(this is for ensure,that `DOM Hierarchy` is completely constructed and you can access `DOM Element`s):

```
window.onload = function(){
   var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
       foo[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
   }
};
```

Actually `getElementsByTagName` returns `NodeList` object,which has some similar functionalities with `Array`,but it's not an `Array`.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work D: the strange thing is, when I use Chrome's console to manually change the attribute using the same JS commands, it works perfectly

Comment: Maybe you should wrap your code into `window.onload=function(){your code};`

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. I tried the original post with jsfiddle, it worked fine. JSFiddle runs script afterload so @Engineer answer is correct.

Comment: @Bluefire Sure, I didn't use jQuery in my answer, because your question is not being tagged with jQuery

Comment: @Bluefire if you are using jquery,then why do you use native DOM manipulators? Simply use `$('a').attr('target','_blank')`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem n I got the answer for that. n the answer is:
use the link to ur javascript after the closing boday tag like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<a src="#">link</a>
<a src="#">link</a>
<a src="#">link</a>
<a src="#">link</a>
<a src="#">link</a>
<a src="#">link</a>

<input type="text" size="20"><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br><br>

<script src="JavaScript/alert.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```